# boost asio detecting / avoiding reception buffer overflow

Tags: c++, networking, boost, boost-asio

Consider a client sending data to a server using TCP, with boost::asio, in "synchronous mode" (aka "blocking" functions).

Client code (skipped the part about query and io_service):

```
tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
tcp::socket socket( io_service );
boost::asio::connect( socket, endpoint_iterator );
std::array<char, 1000> buf = { /* some data */ };
size_t n = socket.send( boost::asio::buffer(buf) );
```

This will send the whole buffer (1000 bytes) to the connected machine.

Now the server code:

```
tcp::acceptor acceptor( io_service, tcp::endpoint( tcp::v4(), port ) );
tcp::socket socket( io_service );
boost::system::error_code err;
std::array<char, 500> buff;
size_t n = socket.read_some( boost::asio::buffer(buff), err );
std::cout << "err=" << err.message() << '\n';
```

- What this does: client sends 1000 bytes through the connection, and server attempts to store it in a 500 bytes buffer.
- What I expected: an server error status saying that buffer is too small and/or too much data received.
- What I get: A "Success" error value, and n=1000 in the server.

What did I miss here ? Can't ASIO detect the buffer overflow ?
Should I proceed using some other classes/functions (streams, maybe?)

Refs (for 1.54, which is the one I use):

- [buffer function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html)
- [TCP socket `read_some()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/read_some.html)
- [TCP socket `send()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/send.html)

Answer (score 1):

You're seriously misunderstanding TCP.

TCP is a byte stream. There's no packet boundary inside a TCP stream. Until you close the socket, all bytes form a single stream. (unlike UDP)

Boost.Asio knows this. As long as the stream is open, it can't say how big the stream will eventually be. If you've got a 500 byte buffer, Boost Asio can fill it with the first 500 bytes of the (potentially unbounded) TCP stream.

However, `read_some` just looks at what's already available. In your case, with just 1000 bytes, it's entirely expected that the whole 1000 bytes are available on your network card. There's no error in that part. It jsut doesn't fit in your buffer, but that's not a problem on the network side.

Neither TCP nor UDP have a way to communicate back that the receiver was expecting a smaller packet. That's application-level logic, and you handle it on the application level. For instance, HTTP has `413 Payload Too Large`. Therefore, Boost.Asio doesn't offer a standard mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm ok with TCP, the thing is I can't understand why ASIO isn't able to **count** the incoming bytes and comparing that to the size of the provided buffer. FWIW, I also tried with the second form of the function: `socket.read_some( boost::asio::buffer(buff,500), err );`: similar behavior.

Comment: @kebs: It is counting them. Asio won't write outside your array. It knows `std::array<char,500>` is 500 bytes. There's no point in manually specifying that, that indeed does not change a thing. The second format can be useful e.g. if you want to use only the first 400 bytes of a 500 byte buffer, leaving 100 bytes for some other purpose.

Comment: To make it clear (from the last § of your answer), I am **not** asking for a mean to communicate the overflow event to the client, only to detect it locally!

Comment: So ASIO is counting bytes but it doesn't signal this overflow to user code, although it has all the needed information. Well, I suppose there is a rationale behind this, seems odd to me. So I guess I have to define a 2-step protocol with size of second message included in first message.

Comment: @kebs: Have a peek at HTTP `Content-Length`. You might be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanks, at present I'm not using HTTP, I need to make up a specific protocol on top of TCP. But switching to HTTP is also considered in the future.

Comment: @kebs: I'm bringing up HTTP because it's well-known, well-understood, and generally considered well-designed. When HTTP provides a certain functionality, you can assume it's missing from TCP. So by understanding HTTP, you gain relevant experience for designing your own custom protocol.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But again, what I'm missing is not on the TCP layer, it's about ASIO that lacks signaling an overflow. But, as I said, I'm sure the designer had its reasons (that I don't understand at present, but maybe it will come ;-) ).

Comment: @kebs: That is being too friendly towards Boost Asio. The unforgivable design flaw of Boost is that they have no abstraction of growable buffers. It should have been possible to point a `buffer` to an empty string or vector. (And on an unrelated note, the lack of a decent timeout mechanism is also killing in real-world code)

Comment: Sidenote: Are you aware of competing libraries with similar capabilities ? Any insights on Poco for example ?

Answer (score 0):

You did receive 500 bytes and may read the last 500 bytes by calling asio again. Just saying this as it seems to me that you misundertood the behaviour of asio.